# Where to put business logic that spans multiple models in Django

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-models

You don't need to read all this post to help me answer the question, the rest of this post is only the context where the question came, but the general question is:

**Where to put business logic that spans multiple models in Django?**

some possibilities:

- Some View? (I don't think so, it must work in the admin and several views, DRY)
- Save methods in model/forms?(how?)
- Clean methos in model/forms?(how?)
- split the logic and use signals?(how?)
- Other?

**Context:**

I have this models:

1. Department: Reference different departments in a company (risk, finance,IT,...)
2. Employee: May belongs to only one department for a period of time and then change to other department.
3. Project: Each Department can have multiple projects, and a project belongs to multiple departemnts.
4. Membership: intermediate table between the Employee and Department ManyToMany relationship that includes other fields like join_date and leave_date, important field are fk:Department, fk:Employee
5. History: intermediate table between Membership and Project that let me know which employee was involved in wish project wen he was working in some department, important fields are fk:Membership, fk:Project.
6. CurrentProjects: table that relates departments with the projects they are working on currently.

suppose I'm in the Django admin and I go the department Risk, and Risk has currently Project1 and Project2 assigned. when I add a new employee "Jhon Smith" (for example,using an inline form in Department) and press the save button, I want the model History gets updated with this information:

```
Membership table (only important fields):

pk   Department   Employee     join_date   leave_date
20   Risk         Jhon Smith   xxxx        xxxx


History Table (only important fields):

Membership   Project
20           Project1
20           project2
```

I mean when a new employee gets assigned to a new department all the actual projects from that department must be assigned to that Membership employee-department in the table History.

the question is where to put this logic in Django? as you can see this logic involves multiples models, some posibilities are:

- In some view (I don think so, it must work in the admin interfase and in other places)
- In the clean method of the Membership, Department or Employee model/form?
- In the save method of the Membership, Department or Employee model/form?
- I have to split the logic and use something like signals? (some example?)
- Others?
- I'm over complicating everything? =)

Considerations: It would be nice if the code could generate a valueerror at any point in the process and the user/admin could be able to see this error in the unbounded form.

Comment: @jdi I'm reviewing the subject right now, but do you have some insights on how to use them for this scenario?

Comment: See my answer. I talk about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just commenting on the aspect of where the logic should live. This all sounds like model logic to me. Django has a slightly mixed concept of MVC. When its purely data relation I believe its all model logic. I would recommend putting the methods as close to the model they affect as possible and simply make the smallest call possible from the triggering model.

If you are very concerned with decoupling the apps, then you could use signals. Instead of Model A knowing it needs to call XYZ during a save, it goes the other way. Model A just emits a signal. XYZ would be responsible for being connected to the signal. You can even make your signal definitions in a completely general project app, in which case neither the triggering or receiving Models know about eachothers actions. It just binds them.

There are some built in signals, such as before and [after a save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) on a model, which means if you are looking for a save trigger you won't have to emit something custom. But lets say at various point of one models logic you need to emit a custom signal like "Name changed", you could emit your own.

**Model A**

```
import django.dispatch

name_changed = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["name"])

class ModelA:
    ...

    def foo:
        # something happened here
        name_changed.send(sender=self, name=the_name)
```

**Model B, C, D**

```
from myApp.modelA import name_changed

name_changed.connect(modelB.handle_name_change, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
name_changed.connect(modelC.handle_name_change, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
name_changed.connect(modelD.handle_name_change, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
```

Personally I have a habit of creating a utils.py module for apps that need some general "controller model" logic. They are more like actions or helpers.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm trying to use this approach right now but I still have doubts if there is a better method,so I'll keep researching and posting,moreover,  I'm courious about your utils.py file, what kind of code do you have there? =)

Comment: @javier: utils just might be functions like: `do_something_with_something`. Basically I just try to keep the amount of heavy logic off the model and limit it to simple ways of pulling and representing data.  I wouldn't really get worked up over the right or wrong place to put the code. signals are usually helpful when you are designing an app that is meant to be distributed and used with any other project. You allow the project owner to connect to the signals of your app. But if you are designing you own project, theres no harm in one app importing from another and using logic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that "history" table you have there. I don't know what kind of information you have in your `Project` table. But if every project have a start and end date, your history table is handling duplicate information. In this case, if you want to know in which project has worked an employee, you just need to know in which rage of dates this employee have worked for the department and then you need to find the projects of that department that were developed between the previous date range.

I hope you understand my point. If no, please tell me so i can explain it better (maybe with an example).

But as i understand your problem and your models, i think you don't need that history table. It will duplicate information...

So, if your `Project` model have this information (range of dates) the solution should live in a manager, because it is just a matter of find the information you want that live in multiple tables...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand your point but the truth is that the logic is a little bit more complicated than that,the dates are not reliable only the table of actual projects, but even if the dates are reliables, I would like to know where is the best place to put this bussiness logic that spans on multiples models.

Comment: I think the answer is in models. I wouldn't change the save method of a model, because i think it should be a silly method, just to manage database issues for that model/object. So, i think it should be in a form save method because it envolves more than one model to save. If you want to control that everything is consistent, you can add that logic into the form clean method.

Comment: @marianobibanchi i'm trying to understand your comment, are you propossing that the bussiness logic that spans on multiples models must be managed from the form or forms of those models? what do you think about the DRY principle if I have to have many forms for the same model plus a rest api and the django admin?

Comment: I think you can make your own "FormMixin" to handle the save and clean methods. Obviously, i don't know exactly what kind of forms are you using and how complex they are. It was just an idea of how to acomplish your work. Again, i don'think that altering your model's save method is the answer. Forms can handle object saving methods and i think are better for handle multi-model logic. But it has its bad side: if you handle something on the console, you can break that business logic you add to your forms...

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll explore this option a little bit more. =)